# Prime NG Data Table Underscore Issue

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I am utilising the PrimeNG DataTable UIcomponent on one of my websites. I am making use of the row grouping functionality http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/rowgroup

On the whole everything is working well except for that a rouge underscore (_) is getting placed in front of each of the group headings. E.g using the examples they provide in the link above, rather than the grouping on brand been Audi, BMW etc it is _Audi, _BMW.

I have even tried copying their examples like for like and I still get an underscore placed in front of the grouping text. So for example:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars1" sortField="brand" rowGroupMode="subheader" groupField="brand" expandableRowGroups="true"
        [sortableRowGroup]="false">
    <p-header>Toggleable Row Groups with Footers</p-header>
    <template pTemplate="rowgroupheader" let-rowData>{{rowData['brand']}}</template>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="price" header="Price">
        <template let-col let-car="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <span>{{car[col.field] | currency:'USD':true:'.0-0'}}</span>
        </template>
    </p-column>
    <template pTemplate="rowgroupfooter" let-car>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:right">Total Price</td>
        <td>{{calculateGroupTotal(car['brand']) | currency:'USD':true:'.0-0' }}</td>
    </template>
</p-dataTable>
```

And the data: -

```
cars1 = [
{ "brand": "VW", "year": 2012, "color": "White", "vin": "dsad231ff" },
{ "brand": "Audi", "year": 2011, "color": "Black", "vin": "gwregre345" },
{ "brand": "Renault", "year": 2005, "color": "Gray", "vin": "h354htr" },
{ "brand": "BMW", "year": 2003, "color": "Blue", "vin": "j6w54qgh" },
{ "brand": "Mercedes", "year": 1995, "color": "White", "vin": "hrtwy34" },
{ "brand": "Volvo", "year": 2005, "color": "Black", "vin": "jejtyj" },
{ "brand": "Honda", "year": 2012, "color": "Yellow", "vin": "g43gr" },
{ "brand": "Jaguar", "year": 2013, "color": "White", "vin": "greg34" },
{ "brand": "Ford", "year": 2000, "color": "Black", "vin": "h54hw5" },
{ "brand": "Fiat", "year": 2013, "color": "Red", "vin": "245t2s" }
```

];

Displays

[image: row groupings]

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Optimus gave a solutión in his [forum](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=49713&p=154366#p154366)

You need to add this CSS:

```
.ui-datatable a { text-decoration: none !important;}
```